# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, java-8

I'm trying execute my java application in my server but always i'm facing the problem below:

> **HTTP Status 500 - br/webi/servlets/ServletEnviarMensagemDireta :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   br.webi.servlets.ServletEnviarMensagemDireta)**

At my server the java is the 1.8.0_66 and i developed my application with the same version. Follow the screenshots of my project and my server.

[image]

[image]

I already Google and i've found that this problem happens because i'm compiling my project with the different version of the my server... But for me it seems ok.

Observation: My project **was not made** using MAVEN.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Even though your default `java` is version 8, your server is not using this. I suggest you connect to it using `jvisualvm` to see it's actual version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem...

I made what is in this link: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

And reinstall Tomcat7 + oracle-java8-installer .

After this i just appoint the $JAVA_HOME again and everything works fine.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line you can run

```
jcmd {pid} VM.version
```

This will tell you which version it is actually using. I suspect it's not Java 8.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html

Comment: Sorry for the question, but how i'll get pid?

Comment: @pedro.olimpio you can use `Task Manager` (windows) or `top` (Unix) or you can use `jps -lvm` from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your help!